# Using {} with variable in Bash

Tags: bash

What is the difference between using and not using `{}` with the `$variable` in bash?

In the two statements below, which one is modern and recommended way write bash script (bash version 3.2+ above)

```
[~]$ variable=hello
[~]$ echo "$variable world"
hello world
[~]$ echo "${variable} world"
hello world
```

Comment: 100% equivalent. There's no universally accepted convention; which to prefer is a matter of opinion (for my own opinion, I strongly prefer `$foo` over `${foo}` in places where it doesn't matter).

Comment: ...the places where it *does* matter are those where you're parameterizing the expansion, or concatenating it with a constant string whose first character is a legal part of a variable name.

Comment: The difference becomes relevant when you have `"$variable_world"` vs `"${variable}_world"`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you!